# Is it possible to add an argument to a property in aiogram?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm making a multi-lingual functionality for a `aiogram` bot, it's pretty simple at the moment:

```py
class Localization:

    locales = {
        'en': {
            'command': {
                'start': 'Hello!'
            }
        }
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self.__user_lang = dict()

    @property
    def available_langs(self):
        return tuple(self.locales.keys())

    def text(self, id):
        return self.locales[self.user_lang(id)]

    def user_lang(self, id):
        return self.__user_lang.get(id, 'en')

    def set_user_lang(self, id, lang):
        if lang in self.available_langs:
            self.__user_lang[id] = lang
```

I have to call it like this:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    id = message.from_user.id

    await message.answer(locale.text(id)['commands']['start'])
```

I want to change `text` in a `@property` to shorten the entry.

```py
@property
def text(self):
    return self.locales[self.user_lang(id)]
```

This will also allow me to make constructs like this:

```py
@dp.message_handler(lambda m: m.text == locale.text['buttons']['about'])
async def about(message: types.Message):
    pass
```

Not like this:

```py
@dp.message_handler(lambda m: m.text == locale.text(m.from_user.id)['buttons']['about'])
async def about(message: types.Message):
    pass
```

But I absolutely cannot think of how to specify the property for which particular user to get localization.

P.S. I know about `i18n`, but I'm learning and want to try to write everything myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i'm definitely stupid.

I could just get the current user in any function that is called from the handler:

```py
from aiogram import types

@property
def user_lang(self):
    user = types.User.get_current()

    return self.__user_lang.get(user.id, 'ru')
```

And so on...